# Progress bar not updating progress line after the defined interval

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I have timer of about 3 minutes, and I have added a `progress bar` that adds 1 point in  progress bar after each `1860 milliseconds.`

So after `1860000` milliseconds it completes the progress.

The issue is that it fills the progress bar on start, and does not show the loading animation.

This is my code.

```
 countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(186000, 1860) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                progressBar.setProgress(time+=1);
                Log.d("seconds remaining: ", String.valueOf(time));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                finish();
                time=0;
            }
        }.start();

    }
```

**Layout file**

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_background"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline9"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView19" />
```

If i remove `progressDialog.setProgress()` method, it shows empty progress bar, and if i add this line, `progress bar` is auto filled on start.

Comment: where did you get the variable 'time'? what is its value?

Comment: Its 0, on start

Comment: Are you using a separate thread? In that case, you should consider using runOnUiThread activity's method, even though the CoundDownTimer uses an internal Handler. Can you maybe show the full code were the CountDownTimer is created?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding the android:progress=0 in the XML layout element?

Comment: I launches it on Button click, in main UI thread. I also tried setting value of `10 & 5`, but if i set any value, it just fills the whole progress bar

Comment: @Kirmani88 did it work ?

Comment: I tested and It's work, no problem

Answer (score 0):

You should set the progress bar with:

```
<ProgressBar
    ...
    android:max="1860000"
    />
```

Then onTick(), call:

```
progressBar.setProgress(time+=1860);
```

Comment: Also, as suggested by @dglozano, you might need to do setProgress(0); on initialization.

Comment: If you put a constant value as the progress, like 1860, it will be fixed in that value. You should set the progress in relation to how many milliseconds are left in the onTick callback.

Comment: Oh yes! Thats true. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are using a variable, `time`, that is declared and initialized outside the scope of the anonymous class `CountDownTimer`. You can check if `time` has the proper value inside the CountDownTimer by running it in Debug mode or simple doing a `System.out.printnln(time)` before calling the `setProgress`.

To be sure that the value that you are setting in the progress bar is the correct one, simple do the following:

`progressBar.setProgress(100 - millisUntilFinished *100 /186000)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use an async task for this purpose, the code is something like this:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        LongTask timer = new LongTask();
        timer.execute();
    }

    private class LongTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        private static final int INTERVAL = 1860;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(INTERVAL);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }

                Log.d("Milliseconds elapsed: %s", String.valueOf(i * INTERVAL));
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {}

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            int progress = values[0];
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The idea of using `CountDownTimer` is to avoid this boilerplate. Internally, it has its own Handler, so no need to run it in a different thread if it does not do any expensive operation onTick. More info in https://android.jlelse.eu/8-ways-to-do-asynchronous-processing-in-android-and-counting-f634dc6fae4e